# Why is there no to_string(const string&)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have template code which needs to convert some template type to string. For this I overload to_string for my own types. But the type can also be a string already. Then compilation fails, because there is no overload of to_string for type string itself (just returning its argument).

edit:
example code:

```
template<class T>
class TemplatedClass
{
public:

string toString() const
{
    // this should work for both simple types like int, double, ...
    // and for my own classes which have a to_string overload
    // and also for string, which is the reason for my question
    return string("TemplatedClass: ").append(to_string(t_));
}

private:
    T t_;
};
```

Comment: Are you asking us how to solve your problem or why there is no overload you are looking for? For former, please provide MCVE. For latter, it's easy to answer - because such overload would be ridiculous.

Comment: Write it yourself? Also, it would be "better" to use some operator<< or other serialization method that is equally suited for this but more "idiomatic".

Comment: It would be silly to have `to_string` function that takes a string and returns a copy of the string.  You can just do that by yourself with the `operator=` of `std::string`.  What does your code look like that is using `to_string`?

Comment: Also, you need to be careful how you overload `to_string`. Putting your overloads in the `std` namespace is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @rubenvb: I don't think that operator<< would be better as it is quite slow. I want to return a string from a method and using stringstream and its .str() method is at least seven times slower (measured) than using string and its append() method.

Comment: @TartanLlama Is it a good idea to add the to_string(string) overload (and of course not add it to namespace std)? Would you do it in global namespace?

Comment: @mgr I think they should go in the same namespace where the type they convert is defined. When you call `to_string(x)` do `using std::to_string` before and the compiler will either use the overload from `std` or the one you provided by ADL.

Comment: Yeah, do what @Jens said.

Comment: @Jens I want to have to_string(std::string), as I understand your advice tells me to put it in namespace std, because string is in namespace std?

Comment: @mgr No, you almost never put something in namespace standard (there are a few defined exceptions). What you should do is to put types and free functions into the same namespace. For `std::string`, this is of course not possible. In your case, I would make `to_string( std::string const& )` a member function of `TemplatedClass`. Or specialize the class for `std::string`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just write your own templated function with proper overloads as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
std::string toString(const T& t) {
    return std::to_string(t);
}

std::string toString(const char* t) {
    return t;
}

std::string toString(const std::string& t) {
    return t;
}


int main() {
    cout << toString(10) << endl;
    cout << toString(1.5) << endl;
    cout << toString("char*") << endl;
    cout << toString(std::string("string")) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann There's no SFINAE in this. Where do you see a substitution failure?

Comment: @T.C. The template instantiation for std::string won't yield an error?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann No, it won't. Substitution will succeed, and then the template won't be instantiated because the non-template overload is a better match.

Comment: @mgr It'll compile. Just read the previous comments to see why. [Here](http://ideone.com/WhL4VS) you can check it too.

Comment: @EissaN. I stand corrected. My compiler error was a bit long and convoluted (as usual with templates...) and had another root cause.

Answer (score 6):

You can just combine all `std::to_string` and all your `to_string` by `using` derective. And pass `std::string` by value to minimize number of copies:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace convert {
    std::string to_string(std::string s)
    {
        return s;
    }

    template<class T>
    std::string stringify(T&& t)
    {
        using convert::to_string;
        using std::to_string;
        return to_string(std::forward<T>(t));
    }
}

class Foo
{
public:
    operator std::string () const { return "Foo"; }
};

namespace bar {
    class Bar
    {};

    std::string to_string(const Bar&) {
        return "Bar";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string s{"I'm lvalue string"};
    std::cout << convert::stringify(42) << "\n";
    std::cout << convert::stringify(std::string("I'm string")) << "\n";
    std::cout << convert::stringify("I'm c-string") << "\n";
    std::cout << convert::stringify(s) << "\n";
    std::cout << convert::stringify(Foo{}) << "\n";
    std::cout << convert::stringify(bar::Bar{}) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that with my approach you don't need an overload for `const char *` or any other type that is convertible to a string. Also this approach allows a user to add `to_string` overload for any class (it will be found by argument-dependent lookup).

For further optimization `convert::to_string` accepting a string by value can be split into lvalue and rvalue overloads.

Comment: Only suggestion (and it may be entirely invalid depending on the use case) would be to change the input/output to use perfect forwarding of references and then return those references.  If s is large, then there are no allocations and/or the caller doesn't have to worry about moving the string.
`template<class Ch, class Tr, class Alloc>
auto to_string(std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, Alloc> &&s) ->
    decltype(std::forward<std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, Alloc>>(s))
    { return s; }`

Comment: @Andrew yep, that's an option although I don't really like the duality of the contract then. because generic `to_string` may return either a value or a ref. Btw `s` should be forwarded in the return expression. And the auto for the return means that return is done by value. It should be `decltype(auto)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++17 you can use `constexpr` in `if` statements.

You can use it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename Ty>
std::string ToString(const Ty& value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<Ty, std::string>) {
        return value;
    }
    else {
        return std::to_string(value);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << ToString(123) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ToString(123.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ToString("char*") << std::endl;
    std::cout << ToString(std::string("std::string")) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```